# why Array Destructuring can swap two variables without temperory variable

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how it works behind the scenes, why this way can without using a temporary variable to swap the values of two variables.

```
    let arr = [1,2];
    let [first,second] = arr;
    [first,second] = [second,first]
    console.log(first,second);  //2,1
```

Comment: Do you understand how regular array destructuring works? Because this is pretty much all of the explanation here.

Comment: How do you know it isn't using temporary variables behind the scenes?

Comment: it's not using 'temporary variables' but it does create a new array in memory `[second,first]` as the target for the destructuring.

Comment: Though I've not seen it used to reassign individual variables as you are, rather to flip indexes in the array itself `[arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]];` (which is both more opaque and more interesting)

Comment: [Destructuring assignment](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation) uses _two_ variables behind the scenes. And that’s just _this_ set of algorithms. Other abstract operations such as [GetIterator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getiterator) use many more.

Comment: @SebastianSimon counting variables in the engine source gets meta pretty quickly, i hate to think the assembly operations at play

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, Why does it output 2 and 1 instead of 2, 2. `[first,second]=[second,first]` how it works.

Comment: @Ly丶Cooki Why would `console.log(first, second);` output `2 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does create a temporary *value* from both the swapped variables before they are reassigned: the array. This value is anonymous, there is no variable name for it, but you could easily introduce one:

```
const _temp = [second,first];
[first,second] = _temp;
```

Comment: So it is likely

Comment: so can i think it use this way to work.  **arr=[1,2]** **[first,second] = arr**.now first and second variable stored 1 and 2. [first,second] = [second,first] can i understand this code as **[first , second] = [2,1]** ;

Comment: @Ly丶Cooki Yes, precisely. It first builds the array `[2, 1]` from the values that the variables hold, then assigns them back to the variables.